# lnk1104: cannot open 'LIBC.lib' LINK

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

After writing a shader using GLee to my OpenGL project and compiling, I received the error
`LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBC.lib'`. I've tried adding it and ignoring it as others suggested, but not nothing resolved the issue. Is there an alternative way to solve this that I've missed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here are several possible solutions:

1. This may due to code generation conflict. If your `libc.lib`'s thread support is different then your project's settings, this may be causing the problem. If so, right click `project`, then go to `properties->C++->code generation->Runtime Library` and change the value to `Multi-threaded(MT)`.
2. Your `libc.lib` may not support multi threading. Right click `project`, then go to `properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` and change `libc.lib` to  `libcmt.lib`
3. Your application statically link multiple copies of the same library. Right click `project`, then go to `properties->Linker->Input->Ignore Specific Library` and add `libc.lib`
4. Maybe your project needs this lib, but your system doesn't have it. In that case, you have to download the `.lib` file from Microsoft and add the path of where you downloaded it by right clicking `project`, then going to `properties->Linker->General->Additional Library directories`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. My runtime library was set to (MD). Searched Runtime Library documentation and found msvcrtd.lib and added it to the library dependencies along with ignoring LIBC.lib. Now my program compiles like it's suppose to again.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem in MS VC++ 2012 Express with Windows SDK 7.1.

I found this solution from the DISLIN developers :

```
  (i) in MS VC++\Project\<YourProject> Properties pull-down...
 (ii) <YourProject>Property Pages\Ignore Specific Default Libraries : libc.lib
(iii) <YourProject>Property Pages\Additional Dependencies\Edit : libcmt.lib
```

Bingo!