# How to get rid of Error " LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBC.lib' " in VS 13?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

My application is building fine in debug mode but when I build the same application in release mode it throws me this linker error "LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBC.lib'".  I found this question answered here [lnk1104: cannot open 'LIBC.lib' LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965716/lnk1104-cannot-open-libc-lib-link)

But Now I'm migrating from VS 6 to VS 13. I tried the first and third option given there. Yet it didn't work.

On trying the second option, I didnt originally find libc.lib in additional dependencies.

And on trying the fourth option,  libc.lib was not present at the  location in my pc.

So can someone tell me how to fix it in VS 13 or suggest me a place from where I can download that file suggested in option 4??

Comment: Libc.lib is an old name from the previous century, it is libcmt.lib today.  Simplest explanation is that you did not rebuild all of the libraries you link.  Use the /VERBOSE linker option to see more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you linked your library only in Debug mode

in

```
project->properties
```

you can choose  the Configuration (Debug\Release) in the combobox at the top left of the window. Make sure that

```
C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories
```

and

```
Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies
```

options are the same in both Debug and Release mode.

Also maybe you linked library built for Debug to your Release mode, in this case you should change it to library that was built in Release.

Comment: Yeah its the same in both release and debug

Comment: Maybe you linked debug library to your release mode? Debug build libraries usually calls the same as Release, but have letter 'd' in its name.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a big project. I tried `/VERBOSE`, but it didn't help much - it showed that linker is looking for the `libc.lib`, but not *why*. Finally, I did find that there is a static library linked which was built with an old version of VisualStudio. Unfortunately, we don't have the source for that library, so I did as in the "Option 3" from  [lnk1104: cannot open 'LIBC.lib' LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965716/lnk1104-cannot-open-libc-lib-link). Can't say why that didn't work out for you - can you share the errors you got?

So, to identify the library that is causing the linker to try to find `libc.lib`, go through all your static `.lib`s, and check how they were built. If you don't have other clues, search `LIBC` in the `.lib` file itself.